# Undefined Index PHP: Can't Find Form Values

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Complete Newbie to PHP, but trying to do a simple form submit to a MySQL Database. I keep getting the Notice: Undefined index: warning on my form input variables. What could be issue here. The form is on a seperate PHP page submitting to the process.php file.

Form Code:

```
<form name="example" id="example" method="POST" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input size="20" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="city">city</label>
        <input size="20" name="city" id="city" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="state">state</label>
        <input size="20" name="state" id="state" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="zip">zip</label>
        <input size="20" name="zip" id="zip" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">e-mail</label>
        <input size="20" name="email" id="email" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="form_upload">file</label>
        <input size="40" type="file" name="form_data" id="form_data" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit form" name="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Process.php

```
<?php
   mysql_connect("localhost", 'root', '') or die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("practice") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_query("CREATE TABLE user (id INT(5)NOT NULL AUTO, name VARCHAR(30), email     VARCHAR(40), city VARCHAR(40), state VARCHAR(3), zip INT(5) )");
   if (isset($_POST)) {
       $name  = $_POST['first_name'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $city  = $_POST['city'];
       $state = $_POST['state'];
       $zip   = $_POST['zip'];
   }
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('$name', '$email', '$city', '$state', '$zip')");
?>
```

Comment: All `mysql_` functions in php are deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: What index is undefined according to the error message?

Comment: Also, every time you submit a form in our example, you create a table. You should check if it doesn't exist yet before creating.

Comment: Which lines specifically are giving you the notice?  As an side, you need to read up on how to prevent SQL injection attacks, as you code is vulnerable now.  Also, since you are just learning PHP, leanr the right way and don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions.  I would suggest `mysqli` or `PDO` for working with the database.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: It's throwing the error for each form input: $name, $email, $city, etc.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: do a var_dump($_POST)

Comment: i dont see any variable in your form inputs. how it throws errors ?

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured out how to do it with mysqli. Thanks for the additional resources to checkout tadman.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you should change this

```
    if (isset($_POST)){
```

and give an index like that

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

and also

change the query to

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (name , email, city,state, zip)
               VALUES('$name', '$email', '$city', '$state', '$zip')" );
```

and you should escape your variables like that before inserting them.

```
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name) ;
 // and so on
```

last thing is why you create table everytime you submit ? you should check if exist .

Comment: When using `mysql_query`, which is a super bad idea to start with, it's probably better to compose the query with `sprintf` and a long list of `mysql_real_escape_string` calls afterwards. Ugly but necessary.